# NFC into cross-platform application, Xamarin.Android integration

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cross-platform, nfc

I want to work with NFC (read NFC-tags) into cross-platform application
I found the example for NFC for Xamarin.Android on forum of Xamarin. Example works, and i try to do this for cross-platform, but met with obstacles

(`nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter(this);`) NfcAdapter in this case = NULL, but the phone has NFC (example works)
I think the problem is because of the Content
i can't get my content of ContentPage into Android for NfcAdapter, when I moved from ContentPage to the Android class, to access NFC classes on Android, i get content as class NFCWorker_Droid, which does not have access to the screen

I assume that i need to migrate information about ContentPage through the interface, but I can not convert Xamarin.ContentPage to Android.Content

With the help of the interface, I turn to the class that is in the android project
Into `ContentPage` i call method of interface `DependencyService.Get<INFCWorker>().EnableWriteMode();` and move to class into android project

The code below shows the class code that is called in Android

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NFCWorker_Droid))]
namespace TestNavigationPage2.Droid
{
    public class NFCWorker_Droid : Activity,INFCWorker
    {
        public const string ViewApeMimeType = "application/vnd.xamarin.nfcxample";
        public static readonly string NfcAppRecord = "xamarin.nfxample";
        public static readonly string Tag = "NfcXample";
        private bool _inWriteMode;
        private NfcAdapter _nfcAdapter;

public void EnableWriteMode()
        {
            _inWriteMode = true;
            // Get a reference to the default NFC adapter for this device. This adapter 
            // is how an Android application will interact with the actual hardware.
            _nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter(this); 
            // Create an intent filter for when an NFC tag is discovered.  When
            // the NFC tag is discovered, Android will u
            var tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionTagDiscovered);
            var filters = new[] { tagDetected };

            // When an NFC tag is detected, Android will use the PendingIntent to come back to this activity.
            // The OnNewIntent method will invoked by Android.
            //var intent = new Intent(this, GetType());
            //var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            if (_nfcAdapter == null)
            {
                Page4.Instance.GlobalText = "NFC is not supported on this device.";
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayMessage("NFC is here!");
                //_nfcAdapter.EnableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, filters, null);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you use DependencyService, you can't get NfcAdapter???

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT `_nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter(this);` - is null

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT yes, I think that the reason for this is DependencyService, because we lose the screen data,when we move to another class